# How to make internal interface pattern?

Tags: c#, .net, interface, internal

I have many classes (with different base classes and such), which share an interface.

```
public interface IObjectWithSector
{
   Sector Sector {get;}
}
```

But, my Sector base class (which is defined in the same assembly as the interface and all the implementing base classes) has a public void `AddObject(IObjectWithSector obj);` method, which among other things have to contain an `obj.Sector = this;` instruction. This presents a problem. If I make the setter public in the interface all the consumer classes will be able to set Sector, and thus able to circumvent the logic inside my AddObject method. But if I keep it out of my public interface even Sector won't see the setter. I'm thinking about "internal interface", but those things aren't nice, since I can't inherit a public one from them, so it'll be cross-casting anyway.

**What is the best pattern for this?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of providing an interface, provide a base class with an internal setter property. All consumers must derive from this class.

You can't force customers to somehow implement something that only your assembly can see. From the customers point of view, this wouldn't make much sense. If they are required to implement your setter, they will also be able to call it. It is their code in their assembly, after all.

A base class implementation is, however, provided by yourself and can thus have internal members. Customers can extend it, but you are guaranteed that the internal stuff is there, and that only you can see it.

Comment: The correct answer, at least in this case was that my abstraction was weak. Changing some interfaces into base classes, and merging some actually improved my code! Now I only wish there would be a "friend class only" modifier in c#...

Answer (score 1):

You're asking for something with a read-only interface then depending on it to be writable too. Fundamentally, that's a weak abstraction that's going to confuse users even if you work around it by casting to an internal interface.

If it's otherwise appropriate, you can solve the problem by making your `Sector` class a factory for the other objects:

```
public class ConcreteObjectWithSector: IObjectWithSector {
    private Sector sector;
    internal ConcreteObjectWithSector(Sector sector) {
        this.sector = sector;
    }
    // everything else
}

public class Sector {
    public ConcreteObjectWithSector CreateConcreteObjectWithSector() {
        var obj = new ConcreteObjectWithSector(this);
        this.stuff.Add(obj);
        // Other logic
        return obj;
    }
}
```

You don't get a single method that can handle all comers, but you know that your objects' invariants are satisfied and don't have to compromise your abstraction.

Comment: +1: This is a good answer. I think CreateObjectWithSector should be changed to return IObjectWithSector though.

Comment: @TheFogger - in some cases, definitely, but I don't think we have enough information to tell.

Answer (score 0):

it is possible to mix public get with internal set
but it gets messy as the internal get has to use the public get
and one of them needs an explicit declaration (as get and set aren't separate but part of a single property)
IMO the clean solution is to use a setter method

```
internal void SetSector(Sector sector);
```

also note that an internal interface *can* inherit a public interface

```
internal interface IPrivate : IPublic { }
private IPrivate blah = ...
public IPublic Blah { get { return blah; } }
```

works just fine
(this can also work with generic covariance in dot net 4.0 for collections etc.)

Comment: the reason it gets messy is because users of IPrivate need to use IPublic to access the getter ...

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you explicitly implement the internal interface:

```
public interface IObjectWithSector
{
    Sector Sector { get; }
}

internal interface IObjectWithSectorSetter: IObjectWithSector
{
    void SetSector(Sector sector);
}
```

Now you can do:

```
public ObjectWithSector: IObjectWithSectorSetter
{
    public Sector Sector { get { ... } }
    void IObjectWithSectorSetter.SetSector(Sector sector) { ... }
}
```

I don't see it getting messy that way.

**EDIT**: Changed the inheritance order of the interfaces, the way I had it before would give you a inconsistent accesss compiler error.

Comment: -1: A public interface or class can not derive from an internal interface or class. Please correct me if I'm wrong, though.

Comment: @TheFogger: I had the interfaces around, I realized that while revising and changed it while you were down voting :p. I thought you were down voting the edited answer, thats why I was a little bewildered.

Comment: Downvote removed, now it compiles. Race condition, I guess :-)

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are trying to add arbitrary data (a `Sector` instance) to your consumer's objects, which they (your consumers) shouldn't be able to access or change.

There is a way to do this cleanly (actually two ways), without exposing anything, even without forcing consumers to implement your interface.

The first way is to maintain a `Dictionary<object, Sector>` which will hold the `Sector` for every consumer's object. But this way is no good, since you don't know when to remove the object from the dictionary, since you're not managing the lifetime of consumer's object. This will also keep consumer's objects from being garbage collected.

The second (right) way is to use a `ConditionalWeakTable<object, Sector>`, which was made just for this purpose - attaching arbitrary data to objects, without affecting their GC-rooted status. As long as the consumer's object is "alive" (not garbage collected) you can always read its Sector, and the entry gets removed when the object is garbage collected.